# Using hooks and state management tools on a page with dynamic link address in Next JS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, react-context, next.js13

I'm making a sample small e-commerce website on Next JS 13. The problem I am facing and still have not found the answer to is how to add products to the cart from a page with single product description.

The structure of my app is the following:
_app
__products
___[:id]

I know about "use client" directive in order to transform the component from server-side to the client-side. And actually it works in case of my Navbar component or any other pages except [:id]. This page can neither be converted to client-side nor use any other client components as nested ones. In fact even handleButtonClick can not be used to add products to cart. If I try to do all of the above, I get an error:

> ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk app/products/[ failed.
> (error: http://localhost:3000/_next/id%5D/page)

So my question is: **how to use state management and add products to the cart in my case?**
Here is the code of my page in [:id]:

```
import { initMongoose } from "@/lib/mongoose";
import { findAllProducts } from "@/pages/api/products";
import React from "react";
import "./Product.scss";

async function fetchProducts() {
  await initMongoose();
  const products = await findAllProducts();

  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
}

export default async function Product({ params }) {
  const id = params[":id"];
  const products = await fetchProducts();
  const product = products.find((product) => product._id === id);

  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="top">
        <div className="image">
          <img src={product.img}></img>
        </div>
        <div className="info">
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <p className="price">{product.price} €</p>
          <p className="volume">{product.volume} oz</p>
          <p className="ingredients">Ingredients: {product.ingredients}</p>
          <button className="addToCartBtn">Add to cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom">
        <div className="left">
          <h4>About</h4>
          {product.description.split("\\n").map((line, index) => (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              {line}
              <br />
              <br />
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <div className="infoSection">
            <h4>Allergens information</h4>
            <p>Contains milk and eggs. May contain traces of nuts.</p>
          </div>
          <div className="infoSection">
            <h4>Preparation instructions</h4>
            <p>
              Allow the ice cream to sit at room temperature for 5-10 minutes
              before scooping.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="infoSection">
            <h4>Storage instructions</h4>
            <p>Keep frozen at -18°C (0°F) or below.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I wanted to use context or Redux, but the page throws chunk error whenever I try to convert it to client or add any nested component in order to handle the button click.

Answer (score 0):

you get `ChunkLoadError` error in client component because `Mongoose` code works only on the server.

In next.js 13 server component can render client component. so all the `jsx` logic in `Product` page, you write in a separate client component and then render it inside it `Product`

```
export default async function Product({ params }) {
  const id = params[":id"];
  const products = await fetchProducts();
  const product = products.find((product) => product._id === id);

  return (
     // you can pass props to this component
     // this component will handle card logic and you can use hooks
     <ClientComponentForCardLogic/>
  )
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Yilmaz.
However, I pass all the jsx to the separate component as you said and as soon as I add "use client" inside <ClientComponentForCardLogic /> in order to do client-side actions, the same ChunkError returns.

Comment: make sure parent `Product` is server component. maybe u still have `use client`

Comment: Now I removed "use client" from all of the components and pages. I have left it only in the one child Product component rendering jsx. However, I still get this "ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk app/products/[ failed." As soon as I remove "use client" from it, everything works except I can't use client-side functions.

Comment: if `Product` is a server component and you render a client component inside, you should not get any error. but anywhere else if you are using `initMongoose`, that component should be server component. you cannot have mongoose code in a client component. you probably using `initMongoose` somehwere else besides `Product`

Comment: I understand and it all works perfectly (server+client) on all the pages except this one [:id] page. You know, Yilmaz, why I thought that the problem is in this dynamic page address? Because when I rename the folder from [:id] to any of the actual ids in the database, I can use <ClientComponentForCardLogic/> as a client without any troubles and ChunkError.

Comment: interesting. can you try to use different version of next.13. this app directory has too many weird bugs

Comment: I was able to recreate this error even in an empty app. Yilmaz, can you please try to do the following and check if you also get the error? 

1) Create a regular NextJs13 app. 
2) Create Products folder inside app with page.js file inside. 
3) Create [:id] folder inside Products with page.js inside.
4) Create components folder inside app with TestComponents.js inside.
5) Make "use client" inside TestComponent and insert it into the return statement in [:id].
6) I get ChunkError on this stage in localhost:3000/products/any

Comment: Oh my goodness. It seems like I have found the cause of this ChunkError finally! It appears because of the colon in the name of the folder. When I renamed the folder from [:id] to [id] the error has disappeared and child client component works as it should! Shame on me :)